# Ошибка 415 Unsupported Media Type при отправке запроса на SOAP сервис

Tags: java, soap

Что нужно добавить к запросу, чтобы решить эту проблему?

```
public String sendRequest() throws Exception{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String  request ;
        request =   "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:sup=\"http://support.xxxxxxxx.ru\">\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "      <sup:DSPersonFindByIDReq>\n" +
                "         <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "         <sup:CodePasspDepartment></sup:CodePasspDepartment>\n" +
                "         <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "         <sup:DetailFlag></sup:DetailFlag>\n" +
                "         <!--Optional:-->\n" +
                "         <sup:PersonID>10000031788</sup:PersonID>\n" +
                "      </sup:DSPersonFindByIDReq>\n" +
                "   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";


    try {    
        URL obj = new URL(Config.getProperty("url_crmws"));
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        String encoding  = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((
            Config.getProperty("ws_login")+":"+Config.getProperty("ws_password")).getBytes("UTF-8"));

        //подготовка
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");   //передавать постом
        con.setDoInput(true);           //передача запроса на сервер
        con.setDoOutput(true);          //прием ответа
        con.setUseCaches(false);        //без кэширования
        con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type",  "application/xml; charset=utf-8");  //кодировка
        con.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        con.addRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",                         //con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);


        //отправка
        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();


        os.write(request.getBytes());        
        os.flush();
        os.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит, что неправильный `Content-Type`.

Установите для версии SOAP 1.1:

```
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Для версии SOAP 1.2:

```
con.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Это вариант тоже пробовал.  Не помогло

Comment: @SergeyKlunichenko обновил ответ, возможно у вас на сервере версия протокола soap 1.2